# Show DIV.bravo only when DIV.alpha has finished its .delay()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I show `div.Bravo` straight after `div.alpha` has finished it's `.delay(1000)`?

I've tried the following, and found that .bravo occasionally appears when .alpha is still shown. I assume an if statement should be used here, but I haven't been able to conjure anything that works.

```
$(".alpha").delay(1000).hide(0);
$(".bravo").delay(1000).show(0);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use one delay, and switch the elements at the same time:

```
$(".alpha").delay(1000).hide(0, function(){
  $(".bravo").show(0);
});
```

Or use a timeout instead of delay:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
  $(".alpha").hide(0);
  $(".bravo").show(0);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

you can put it in the callback function:

```
$(".alpha").delay(1000).hide(0, function() {
      //whatever you put here will happen after .alpha finishes hiding
      $(".bravo").delay(1000).show(0);
})
```